# What is the name of the backtick (`) key in the XNA Keys enumeration?

Tags: c#, input, xna, naming

I'm looking for the name of the [Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.keys.aspx) enumeration entry corresponding to the backtick <kbd>`</kbd> key (left of the <kbd>1</kbd> key on my keyboard).

Comment: Elideb, he would still not know what the name of the key in the enumeration was...

Comment: @Elideb: Well yes, it rather was. I did say it was a silly question. But I'd like to see you write an XNA program that displays the enum name in question (in less time than it took to get this question answered)...

Comment: Well now that I come to think about it, yes it would work nicely :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think `Keys.OemTilde` is what you need.